# Rest URI design for multiple Post operations on same resource

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am designing an application where user needs to :

```
- Register
- LogIn
- Subscribe to Newsletter
```

As all these operations are done on User resource,will it be good idea to put all three operations with @PostMapping and with three different methods in same Rest controller

OR

Have separate Controller for each operation.

I am also looking for advise on designing uri for these operations.

```
/users/v1/?   - Register User
/users/v1/?   - Log in  User
/users/v1/?   - Subscribe User
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of taste mostly, but typically I put all operations for the same resource in the same controller class. Thus if all these operations are on a `User` resource, I'd put them in a `UserController` class.

The operations are likely to use the same services and beans, so spreading them across multiple controllers doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

For the operations which are going to perform on the same Resource splitting it to an induvial controller is not an ideal way *(except LoginController opinion-based)*. If we *split the controller for each operation you will be ending up with so many controllers which can not be easily maintained.*

Now coming to the URI part. It depends on the requirement. If you have multiple roles for the USER where some resources are available to all, some need to be authenticated. To configure Spring Security easily URI convention matters

*approach 1: (public-private Resources)*

```
/api/v1/public/register -> Avaiable to all
/api/v1/public/login -> Avaiable to all
/api/v1/private/users -> Needs to be authenticated
```

*approach 2: (adding role in endPoint)*

```
/api/v1/public/register -> Avaiable to all
/api/v1/public/login -> Avaiable to all
/api/v1/private/admin/user/remove/id -> Needs to be authenticated with ROLE_ADMIN
/api/v1/private/users/user/id -> Needs to be authenticated with ROLE_USER
```